# Text mining using R to find values

Tags: r, text-mining

I have a long file where the values of different parameters are stored. Here is the very simple example of the data. There are several lines above `C5`. I want to find the value of `ISVEG` and `ISDISP`. I found the command for matlab to find the value of `ISVEG` but I couldn't change that to `R code`

```
C5 MOMENTUM ADVEC AND HORIZ DIFF SWITCHES AND MISC SWITCHES
*
*
C5   ISCDMA  ISAHMF  ISDISP  ISWASP   ISDRY    ISQQ  ISRLID   ISVEG  ISVEGL   ISITB  ISEVER  IINTPG
          0       1       0       0     -99       1       0       0       0       0       0       0
C6 Testing
* 
*
C6  par1  par2 
     10     12
```

Matlab code:

```
% inpfile is the file where the above sample data is stored
fid=fopen(inpfile,'r');
%C5
linestr = getstring(fid,'C5');
linestr = getstring(fid,'C5');
linestr = fgets(fid);
val = str2num(linestr);
isveg = val(8);
```

I think we could use `readLines` but I am stuck after reading the lines. Do I use regular expressions ?

```
sampledata <- readLines("sampledata.txt")
```

**dput(sampledata) added**

```
dput(sampledata)
c("    C5 MOMENTUM ADVEC AND HORIZ DIFF SWITCHES AND MISC SWITCHES", 
"    *", "    *", "    C5   ISCDMA  ISAHMF  ISDISP  ISWASP   ISDRY    ISQQ  ISRLID   ISVEG  ISVEGL   ISITB  ISEVER  IINTPG", 
"              0       1       0       0     -99       1       0       0       0       0       0       0", 
"    C6 Testing", "    * ", "    *", "    C6  par1  par2 ", "         10     12"
)
```

Comment: Is there any sort of organization/format to the text in the file? Meaning, could it be put into some structured form? It doesn't seem so from your sample.

Comment: @RichardScriven I guess the data is not in structured form.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I came up with.  Since the values you are trying to get are both zeroes, and there are other zeroes, I switched the values you're looking for to 10 and 5, and added another row (C7) of the same format with values 20 and 8 (for ISDISP and ISVEG, respectively).
Here's a function, which will likely work on the whole file (provided the formatting is the same on **all** of the lines of interest).

---

Here's the text:

```
text <- "C5 MOMENTUM ADVEC AND HORIZ DIFF SWITCHES AND MISC SWITCHES
*
*
C5   ISCDMA  ISAHMF  ISDISP  ISWASP   ISDRY    ISQQ  ISRLID   ISVEG  ISVEGL   ISITB  ISEVER  IINTPG
          0       1      10       0     -99       1       0       5       0       0       0       0
C6 Testing
*
*
C6  par1  par2
10     12
**
C7   ISCDMA  ISAHMF  ISDISP  ISWASP   ISDRY    ISQQ  ISRLID   ISVEG  ISVEGL   ISITB  ISEVER  IINTPG
          0       1      20       0     -99       1       0       8       0       0       0       0"
```

---

Here's the function, which takes a **single-column** `data.frame` read from `read.csv` as its argument.

```
valueFinder <- 
  function(xx)
  {
    xx[, 1] <- as.character(xx[, 1])
    index <- which(sapply(1:nrow(xx), function(i) grep("(ISDISP|ISVEG)", xx[i, ])) == TRUE)
    aa <- lapply(index, function(j) unlist(strsplit(xx[j, ], " ")))
    ss <- lapply(index, function(z) unlist(strsplit(xx[z+1, ], "[[:space:]]+")))
    d <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, lapply(1:length(ss), function(w){
      ss[[w]][aa[[w]][nzchar(aa[[w]])] == "ISDISP" | aa[[w]][nzchar(aa[[w]])] == "ISVEG"]
      })))
    rownames(d) <- sapply(aa, function(x) x[1])
    colnames(d) <- c("ISDISP", "ISVEG")
    return(d)
  }
```

---

And here's the result, displaying the values and which row they came from.

```
> xx <- read.csv(text = text, header = FALSE)
> valueFinder(xx)
##    ISDISP ISVEG
## C5     10     5
## C7     20     8
```

Comment: This can definitely turned into a function to operate on a larger text file.

Comment: I think that is a nice idea to turn into a function. Could you modify your code to create a function ? Thanks.

Comment: Thank for making a function which might be useful in my real data set.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `read.csv(..., sep='')` at least if the text of interest is on the first row. (If not, add some code to chop the lines of interest)
This gives you a dataframe with your fields of interest:

```
> txt <- read.csv('so.csv', sep='')

> txt
  C5 ISCDMA ISAHMF ISDISP ISWASP ISDRY ISQQ ISRLID ISVEG ISVEGL ISITB ISEVER IINTPG
1  0      1      0      0    -99     1    0      0     0      0     0      0     NA

> txt$ISVEG
[1] 0
> txt$ISDISP
[1] 0

> str(txt)
'data.frame':   1 obs. of  13 variables:
 $ C5    : int 0
 $ ISCDMA: int 1
 $ ISAHMF: int 0
 $ ISDISP: int 0
 $ ISWASP: int -99
 $ ISDRY : int 1
 $ ISQQ  : int 0
 $ ISRLID: int 0
 $ ISVEG : int 0
 $ ISVEGL: int 0
 $ ISITB : int 0
 $ ISEVER: int 0
 $ IINTPG: logi NA
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort. In my real text there are many rows before C5 so I need extra piece of code to use this way I guess.

Comment: Then you just need a line or two extra to only snip and present the lines of interest. Text-processing is not R's strength as you have discovered - I'm sure there's some crufty function with some non-intuitive name. I'm busy now but I'll look at it later.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with. I was wondering whether there is a simple solution.

```
> sampledata <- readLines("C:/Users/jdbaba/sampledata.txt")
Warning message:
In readLines("C:/Users/jdbaba/sampledata.txt") :
  incomplete final line found on 'C:/Users/jdbaba/sampledata.txt'
> linestr <- grep(pattern="C5", sampledata)
> linestr
[1] 1 4

# Since I am interested to read values one line below C5 I used linestr[2]+1
> sampledata[linestr[2]+1]
[1] "              0       1       0       0     -99       1       0       0       0       0       0       0"
> temp <- read.table(text=sampledata[linestr[2]+1], sep="")
> temp
  V1 V2 V3 V4  V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10 V11 V12
1  0  1  0  0 -99  1  0  0  0   0   0   0
> isveg <- as.numeric(temp[8])
> isveg
[1] 0
```